# Magento 2 Fotorama gallery shows white space on the left side when I select thumbnail as a vertical slider

Tags: magento2, fotorama, fotorama-slider, catalog-product

In Magento 2, I will use the Fotorama Gallery thumbnail images as a vertical slider. It works fine for two or more images but when I upload only one image from the admin side and show the image, it gives some white space on the left side and the main image moves to the right side.

I changed the thumbnail image position from horizontal to vertical in the **view.xml** file for creating sliders with vertical navigation images. It's working but when one image is available in the product, it will move to the right side and give white space to the left side, as per the below image. When I change the nav position from vertical to horizontal, it works fine.

[image]